# Highcharts loading all data with xaxis simplified

Tags: highcharts, graphing

When I load all my data into a chart the xaxis gets cluttered and unreadable. I have maybe 120 records per hour that with a certain value. Is there a way in highcharts to load all the data I have and have the xaxis showing the values per hour? As pictured below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIAT3.png

Comment: How your series / data look like?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.line.pointInterval? I would assume setting pointInterval to 3600*1000 = 1 h would achieve what you want? By default this value is 1, hence the cluttering.

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointInterval:  3600 * 1000 // 1 h
        }
    },
```

Also check this fiddle; [samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-pointstart-datetime/](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-pointstart-datetime/)